# python regex matching a group that starts with x and ends with y several lines down

Tags: python, regex

I have a case where I have to break down a string that looks something like this:

```
TASK **********************************  
everything ok 
TASK **********************************  
some text here untill you get dot retry.retry  
TASK **********************************  
everything ok
```

I want to capture only groups that have failed (have .retry at the end)

```
TASK **********************************  
some text here untill you get dot retry.retry
```

So far I've come closest to what I need with the following regex, however, it only captures the first group and only the first group

```
(?m)(TASK.*\.retry)
```

Any suggestions?

edit:

```
re.findall(r"TASK.+?\.retry" , text, flags = re.DOTALL)
```

will find groups if they all end with .retry, this is how the question was originally phrased, but was wrong... my bad.

edit 2:
the duplicate answer does not exclude the groups that are ok, why is this flagged?

Comment: You can try this regex to match what you want.  `(?is)task(?:(?!\.retry|task).)*\.retry`   https://regex101.com/r/LCxVPB/90

Comment: @ThmLee thank you, this worked perfectly

Answer (score 1):

By break down you want every Task until retry.

```
re.findall(r"TASK.+?\.retry" , text, flags = re.DOTALL)
```

Changes :

Since you have to get only the retry parts of the result,
You can get it with a different approach.

```
list_obj = string.split("retry.retry")
repeatable_tasks = []
for each_obj in list_obj[:-1]:
    repeatable_tasks.append("".join(each_obj.rpartition("TASK")[1:]))
```

Comment: `r"(TASK[\s\S]+?\.retry)"` is an alternative that does not require `DOTALL`, in case he wants to use default dot behaviour elsewhere.

Comment: @Zinki but wouldnt this capture it from the first TASK to the last retry in a single group .

Comment: sorry, i updated the question to reflect what i actually need. my bad for not clarifying. this indeed finds the groups but will not exclude the ones that are ok (which is the edit on the original question)

Comment: It wouldn't for the same reason your answer doesn't (using non-greedy operator `?`). `.` with DOTALL flag is equivalent to `[\s\S]`.

Comment: this doesnt' split up the groups properly, i end up getting 1 match (that is too long):  


`TASK **********************************  
everything ok  
TASK **********************************   
some text here untill you get dot retry.retry`

Comment: @Mazimer, look at the changes added to the answer, hopefully that solves your problem